# Fabric.io Beta Distribution via Gradle - Group Alias - Invitation Email

Tags: google-fabric

I need some assistance understanding an aspect of this function provided by fabric

As far as I understand by setting:
ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "testers"
When the APK is uploaded, those members of that testers group should receive an email  invitation to test.

This is not the case in my instance.

The APK does upload and the users are associated with this build as can be seen by the console (it says 9 invited). But no emails are actually sent out.

I would prefer to use the group alias as this saves me having to manage email addresses in the gradle file.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Actually even if I specify the CSV of test emails.
The emails are not landing on the target users email accounts.
I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. There's a couple of different reasons why you're testers wouldn't be notified.

1) If you have the following set, then testers would not be notified:

```
ext.betaDistributionNotifications=false
```

2) If a tester was invited, but never accepted the original invite, they won't be notified of new builds since they are not testing.

3) If the build and version number of the build are the same and you are re-distributing the build, then only new testers would be notified.

4) If the tester unsubscribed to update from Beta about app updates, then they won't be notified.

5) If for some reason a tester's address is invalid, then our mail server may have a bounce for their email address. If you think that this is happening, then emailing the Fabric support team at support(at)fabric(dot)io would be your best bet.

6) The tester could be getting the email, but not seeing it and it could be in a spam or junk folder.

Comment: Thank you kindly for that response. 
The process is much clearer now.

It turns out the email issue was the invitation acceptance for the debug build (where there was none.)

With correct invitations for the other builds the users are now getting their respective email notifications.