# Fabric.io Beta Distribution via Gradle - Emails Sending Issue

Tags: google-fabric

I need some assistance with regards to Beta distribution, and am at a loss for where to look or how to troubleshoot this.

I have already posted a question but I believe it to be in the wrong area, and perhaps posting here will have better results.

With that said here is the link regarding the question, relating to the title.

[Fabric.io Beta Distribution via Gralde - Group Alias - Invitation Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603692/fabric-io-beta-distribution-via-gralde-group-alias-invitation-email)

Thanks kindly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fabric.io Beta Distribution via Gralde - Group Alias - Invitation Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603692/fabric-io-beta-distribution-via-gralde-group-alias-invitation-email)

Comment: I voted to close this since it's a duplicate of another post, but I'll respond there.